# Why is it said that shear transformations preserve relative distances of collinear points?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

From:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping
"However a shearing does preserve the area of geometric figures and the alignment and relative distances of collinear points."

But suppose we look at the points (0,1) and (0,0), then the rightward shear transforms the two to become (1,1) and (0,0). However, hasn't the distance relative distances of these collinear points changed? (triangle inequality)

Comment: If you are talking about colinear points, it makes no sense to consider only two $-$ any two points are colinear! That sentence applies to three or more points on a straight line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim isn't that distance is preserved: it's that *relative* distance is preserved.

The ratio of the length of $(0,0)-(0,1)$ (I use this notation to indicate the line segment connecting the points) to itself is the same as the ratio of the length of $(0,0)-(1,1)$ to itself, so we see relative distance is preserved in your example.

A less trivial example is to include the point $(0,3)$ which transforms to $(3,3)$:

- The ratio of $(0,0)-(0,1)$ to $(0,1)-(0,3)$ is a $1:2$ ratio
- The ratio of $(0,0)-(1,1)$ to $(1,1)-(3,3)$ is also a $1:2$ ratio